# IPython qtconsole figure window

Tags: python, ipython, interactive, qtconsole

I realise that tons of people have asked questions about the interactive figure window in IPython but I haven't yet found an answer to my problem.
I'm using the IPython qtconsole for plotting, and I'd like it if

```
 plt.plot(x,y) (plt = matplotlib.pyplot)
```

would make an interactive figure window pop up BY DEFAULT.

I can get an interactive window for my plot using `%pylab qt` but I have to use this command every time before plotting, and I'd prefer to just make this a default setting. I am using IPython qtconsole version 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into iPython [Profiles](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html).  You should be able to either change the "default" profile to set the `matplotlib` output be going to `qt` by default or create another profile and have a convenient alias in your shell set up.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your answer. I checked the link you posted, but I think it's a bit advanced for me. Could you be a bit more specific as to where I should look for matplotlib settings? Thanks.

Comment: just run `ipython profile create` to create a default set of config files—it'll say what it's creating.  Then open `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` and set `c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib = 'qt'`

Comment: Sorry didn't work for me - 'ipython profile create' returned a syntax error, but i found the ipython_config.py files in the folder and added the setting you suggested. However nothing changed, I still don't get a figure window (even after restarting the kernel).

Comment: if you could update the question with more details, exactly what you typed and what output the commands returned.